# Wind Shield - which makes?

Tags: zoom, wind-protection

Hey all,

I'm looking for a mini wind shield for my Zoom H1. I have looked and seen that Rycote don't make one for it. However, a company called [Redhead](http://www.redheadwindscreens.com/blog/zoom-h1-windscreen/) do. Has anyone used Redhead products?

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used one but here's a great demonstration on how effective it can be:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MyszfDUgzAE

[youtube]MyszfDUgzAE[/youtube]

Comment: Ok, that needs to be added to my kit. Thanks for the info.

Comment: uhm what the hell is the alien legs tripod thing ? ... been looking for something like that lately for my D-50

Comment: alien legs = gorillapod. http://joby.com/gorillapod.

Comment: I think this is a better link cause its the same recorder you got but yeah its pretty much the same thing lol http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7qwg1B64Jc

Comment: I just ordered two, one each for my H1 and H2.

Answer (score 5):

I have a Redhead and I can't say enough good things about it.  I've had my Zoom H4 since they were first released and I hardly used it because of how sensitive to wind the on-board microphones are.  When I bought the Redhead it turned my H4 from a useless recorder to something I never leave the house with.  Just yesterday I was recording on coming car-bys with the window open as I was driving down the road!

And naturally being the Star Wars geek that I am, I bought the Lil'Chewy  :)

Comment: Another endorsement for Redhead, works fantastic under high wind conditions with the H2.

Answer (score 4):

Redhead are great - have one for my Sony PCM-M10 as I couldn't track down the rycote version.  Works as well as any mini-windshield can I think. And slightly off topic but the Joby gorillapod is a great addition too...

Answer (score 1):

I've got a pair of Redheads (gunmetal and black), and I love them -- after awhile, a naked h4n just looks wrong.

I just ordered the Portable Recorder Suspension Kit from Rycote, which comes with a WindJammer, so I plan on doing a head-to-head comparison with fans.

Comment: Hey @Dave, I lost my Rycote for the Zoom H4n, now I'm thinking of getting the Redhead. Did you happen to do the head-to-head comparison? Would love to hear your feedback. 

Answer (score 0):

sorry for jumping on your thread but its related  .. I was on location in Cuba this past week and found the stock Sony windscreen for my D-50 wouldn't cut out enough wind. I feel like I needed a giant fuzzy hat for my D-50 the wind was quite strong .. any suggestions for a larger windscreen or a better solution for strong wind ??

Comment: Man this thread was started an age ago. @studio13 - Having lived with the RedHead for a while now I'd say check them out.

Comment: @ianjpalmer Well I wish I read your comment before typing in my huge suggestion lol.

Answer (score 0):

I buy mine from Shirley who owns Gig Wig Windscreens in Tennessee USA.

http://www.GigWigWindscreens.com